# Plummer and Coulomb kernel for the Poisson equation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics

Consider the $d$-dimensional Coulomb "kernel" defined by:
\begin{equation}
x \in \mathbb{R}^{d} \mapsto g(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\log \frac{1}{|x|} & \text { if } d=2 \\
\frac{1}{|x|^{d-2}} & \text { if } d \geq 3
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
It is known that $g$ satisfies, in the sense of Swchartz distributions, the Poisson equation:
\begin{equation}
\Delta g = - c_d \delta_{0}
\end{equation}
where $c_d$ is some constant, $\delta_{0}$ the dirac mass at the origin and $\Delta$ the Laplace operator.

Sometimes the Coulomb kernel is "softened" because it has a singularity and one considers the "Plummer kernel" defined by:
\begin{equation}
p_{\epsilon}(x) = \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{|x|^{2}+\epsilon^{2}}\right)^{d-2}}
\end{equation}
for $\epsilon >0$.

My question is: does this kernel also satisfy some Poisson like equation ? More generally are there some known PDE for which this kernel is the solution ?

Comment: Every function satisfies a Poisson equation with some RHS. For your function, the RHS is a smooth function which tends to $\delta$ when $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes indeed but I was wondering if we could characterize it more precisely (like in the case $\epsilon = 0$)

Answer (score 3):

The radial Laplacian in spherical coordinates is
$$\Delta=\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+\frac{n-1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}.$$
By differentiating we obtain
$$\Delta p_\epsilon=-\epsilon^2n(n-2)(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{-1-n/2}.$$
This RHS tends to $-c_n\delta_0$ when $\epsilon\to 0$.